# jQuery Check SelectedIndex For Each Dropdown On Page By Class

Tags: jquery, dynamic, each, selectedindex, dropdown

I have a page where dropdowns are dynamically created with the class "issueDropDown". I'm trying to check the page for all the dropdowns with the class "issueDropDown" to see whether they were changed or not. Basically, if the selectedIndex of each dropdown (which is disabled) is still set, I execute something.

Example:

```
<select class='issueDropDown'>
    <option selected disabled>Select Type</option>
    <option value="1">Type 1</option>
    <option value="2">Type 2</option>
</select>
```

What I have so far which isn't working (without checking for each):

```
$('body').on('change', '.issueDropDown', function() {
    $('.issueDropDown').change(function(){
        var selIndex = $(".issueDropDown").filter(function(){
       return this.selectedIndex > 0;
    }).length;

    // I'll execute something here once I check that it's still "Select Type"
    alert('test: ' + selIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var selIndex;
$('body > .issueDropDown').change(function(){
          selIndex = $(".issueDropDown").filter(function(){
          return this.selectedIndex > 0;
        });

        // If selIndex is defined, do something.
        if(selIndex) {

        } else {
           // selIndex is not defined, so do something else.
        }

});
```

In your code, selIndex is also out of scope.

Edit: If you are changing these elements dynamically with jQuery, you could also look into [MutationObserver](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) rather than trying to iterate through each element.